# Firebase realtime rules how to check if node with AutoID contains correct data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to write a firebase rule that checks to see if you have access to a child of one node by checking the data of another node. The issue I am having is accessing the other node's data because it is stored under an AutoId. How would I access the data under the AutoId?

Here is my database structure:

```
{
  "products" : {
    "Product001" : {
      "ownerId" : "User002",
      "productName": "Name"
    },
    "product002" : {
      "ownerId" : "User001",
      "productName": "Name"
    }
  },
  "shares" : {
    "share001" : {
      "accepted" : true,
      "ownerId" : "User002",
      "productId" : "Product001",
      "userEmail" : "example@email.com"
    },
    "share002" : {
      "accepted" : true,
      "ownerId" : "User001",
      "productId" : "Product002",
      "userEmail" : "email@exaple.com"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "User001" : {
      "email" : "example@email.com",
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Smith"
    },
    "User002" : {
      "email" : "email@example.com",
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the section of the rules that is causing me a problem:

```
"products":{
  "$productId":{
     ".read":"root.child('shares').child($shareId).child('productId').val() === $productId && root.child('shares').child($shareId).child('ownerId').val() === auth.uid",
     ".write":"root.child('shares').child($shareId).child('productId').val() === $productId && root.child('shares').child($shareId).child('ownerId').val() === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Essentially, a user is only allowed to access a premises if they are in a share that contains their information.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in security rules to *query* or *search* another node, as the performance of that would be way too unreliable. So in your current data model it is not possible to allow the user access to a product if they have any shares for that product.

You'll need to have a list somewhere in a knowable path of the products the user can read. For example, say that you keep a list of the products the user is interested in:

```
  "interests" : {
    "User001" : {
      "Product001": true,
      "Product002": true
    },
```

Now you can allow the user access to all products they follow with:

```js
"products":{
  "$productId":{
     ".read":"root.child('interests').child(auth.uid).child($productId).exists()",
     ".write": ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, shame this is the case. This workaround has fixed my issue.